# Xamarin Android Player Connect to LAN/Internet

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, virtualbox

I has install Virtual box in my Windows 7 64 bit machine.  I has install Xamarin Android player and Xamarin forms into my VS 2015 Community version.  I wish to test the xamarin forms with the web service in my local machine.  But the Xamarin Android Player not able to find my web service.  How I can make the Xamarin Android player connect to my LAN?  It is running Host-Only Network for Adapter 1, while Adapter 2 is Bridge.  In the Xamarin Android Simulator, I on the Wifi but it not able to scan the Wifi list.  Please guide me to the correct way how I can setup the simulator.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin Android player is cancelled officially , so my recommendations for you are the following .

1. Uninstall Xamarin Android Player
2. Uninstall Virtual box
3. Go to device manager and remove all the failing network adapters.
4. Restart and enable virtualization from your bios

**If you want to keep your Windows 7 then**

5. Go and download HAXM from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)
6. Go to your android sdk manager from your visual studio
7. Go down to Extras and install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator

By doing this , now you can use the emulators which comes with Android SDK and they are great.

**If you want to upgrade to Windows 10 (Recommended)**

1. Go to *Turn Windows features on or off*
2. Enable Hyper-V (probably it is enabled by default)
3. Download and install the visual studio Emulator for Android from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx) and enjoy.

There is another emulator that will things for you, and it is called Genymotion. But in order to install this you have to turn of your Hyper-V from Features

Comment: if I wish to use the GenyMotion, how I can make it able to test my Visual Studio Xamarin Form Project?

Comment: Thanks @BraveHeart, I change to use GenyMotion and the simulator can online now.